# Run terminal command on a server

Tags: networking, terminal, remote, file-transfer, file-server

I have a linux machine and I'm connecting to a server using its IP address. I go to the finder (Nautilus) address bar and type `smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` then it asks for my credentials and I enter then then the server is mounted and I have access to its folders.

I wonder how I can run a terminal command on the server from the linux machine? The reason me wanting this is that I want to run `iPerf` on both the server and linux machine so I can check the transfer speed between the linux machine and the server.

Comment: @roaima I go to the finder (Nautilis) address bar and type smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx then it asks for my credentials and I enter then then the server is mounted and I have access to its folders.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is set up for remote access just use the `ssh` command locally:

```
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

You might need to specify the remote username if it's not the same as the one you use locally:

```
ssh remoteuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

For further details there are many, many tutorials available on using `ssh` (and of course the man pages, such as `man ssh`).

Comment: I tried both and I get this message "The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established"

Comment: @Tak that's right. It can't. That's why the next but one line asks, "_Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?_".